# Emit concourse metrics

Tags: logstash, monitoring, metrics, concourse

I am trying to create an ELK monitoring setup for my BOSH and Concourse setup. I am using [syslog release](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/syslog-release) to emit BOSH event to my elk stack, but I also need the logs from Concourse CI. From the official [concourse documentation](https://concourse.ci/metrics.html) they talk about a riemann setup, however I would like to avoid that and keep my data in ELK.

Is there a way I can forward all the concourse CI logs in my BOSH deployment to my ELK stack with something like a syslog forwarder? or elasticbeat?

I use the standard concourse [deployment.yml](https://concourse.ci/clusters-with-bosh.html)

Comment: If you have a BOSH deployed Concourse, the [syslog release](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/syslog-release) should be sufficient.

Have you configure that release to forward to the ELK stack address?

Comment: Yes I have, I am using this configuration for my bosh manifest.yml https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-deployment/blob/master/syslog.yml but it only emit BOSH events but nothing from concourse itself. 

If the expected behaviour is that syslog forwards logs from the deployments the there must be something wrong with the yml snippet and in that case can you see what it is?